# How to use a predicate for one-to-many managed objects in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate, nsmanagedobject

I currently have two managed objects for Core Data that has one-to-many relationship.

**Goal**

```swift
extension Goal {

    @nonobjc public class func createFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Goal> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Goal>(entityName: "Goal")
    }

    @NSManaged public var title: String
    @NSManaged public var date: Date
    @NSManaged public var progress: NSSet?

}
```

**Progress**

```swift
extension Progress {

    @nonobjc public class func createFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Progress> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Progress>(entityName: "Progress")
    }

    @NSManaged public var date: Date
    @NSManaged public var comment: String?
    @NSManaged public var goal: Goal

}
```

For every goal, you can have multiple `Progress` objects. The problem is when I request a fetch for `Progress` with a particular `Goal` as the predicate, nothing is being returned.  I have a suspicion that I'm not using the predicate properly.

This is how I request them.

1. First, I fetch `Goal` for a table view controller:

```swift
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Goal>!

if fetchedResultsController == nil {
    let request = Goal.createFetchRequest()
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)
    request.sortDescriptors = [sort]
    request.fetchBatchSize = 20
    
    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: self.context, sectionNameKeyPath: "title", cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
}

fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = goalPredicate

do {
    try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
} catch {
    print("Fetch failed")
}
```

2. And pass the result to the next screen, `Detail` view controller:

```swift
if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Detail") as? DetailViewController {
    vc.goal = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

3. Finally, I fetch `Progress` using the `Goal` as the predicate from `Detail` view controller:

```swift
var goal: Goal!
let progressRequest = Progress.createFetchRequest()
progressRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "goal == %@", goal)

if let progress = try? self.context.fetch(progressRequest) {
    print("progress: \(progress)")

    if progress.count > 0 {
        fetchedResult = progress[0]
        print("fetchedResult: \(fetchedResult)")
    }
}
```

`Goal` is being returned properly, but I get nothing back for `Progress`. I've tried:

```swift
progressRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "goal.title == %@", goal.title)
```

or

```swift
progressRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY goal == %@", goal)
```

but still the same result.

Following is how I set up the relationship:

```swift
// input for Progress from the user
let progress = Progress(context: self.context)
progress.date = Date()
progress.comment = commentTextView.text

// fetch the related Goal
var goalForProgress: Goal!
let goalRequest = Goal.createFetchRequest()
goalRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title == %@", titleLabel.text!)

if let goal = try? self.context.fetch(goalRequest) {
    if goal.count > 0 {
        goalForProgress = goal[0]
    }
}

// establish the relationship between Goal and Progress
goalForProgress.progress.insert(progress)

// save
if self.context.hasChanges {
    do {
        try self.context.save()
    } catch {
        print("An error occurred while saving: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Comment: `var goal: Goal!` declares the variable but it is not set

Comment: I'm passing the value from the previous screen, `vc.goal = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)`, and using it as the predicate.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, where do you run the fetch code in `DetailViewController`? And rather than `try?` catch the error.

Comment: No worries. I run the fetch code in `viewDidLoad()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't need to refetch the data. You can get the progress from the relationship

- Declare `progress` as native `Set`

  ```
  @NSManaged public var progress: Set<Progress>
  ```
- In `DetailViewController` delete the fetch code in `viewDidLoad` and declare

  ```
  var progress: Progress!
  ```
- In the first view controller filter the progress

  ```
  let goal = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
  if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Detail") as? DetailViewController,
     let progress = goal.progress.first(where: {$0.goal.title == goal.title}) {
      vc.progress = progress
      navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
  }
  ```

And consider to name the to-many relationship in plural form (`progresses`)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was giving me an error that `Progress` doesn't have `title` so I changed it to `$0.goal.title `, but now when I click on the cell of the table, the cell gets highlighted, but doesn't navigate to the `Detail` view controller for some reason.

Comment: Right, I updated the answer. Then check whether the relationships are set up correctly in the model.

Comment: I updated my question to include how I set up the relationship. I fetch the goal first and then `insert(_:at: )` the `Progress` object before saving the context.

Comment: I mean the relationships in the Core Data model, especially the inversion. Please use the debugger, set breakpoints and watch variables.

Comment: Oh I see.  I have each other for the inversion.  `progress` has `goal` as the inversion and `goal` has `progress` as the inversion.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that it's due to Core Data Fault where Core Data lazy loads the data and unless you explicitly access the data, the value will not be displayed.

You can either do something like the following:

```swift
let goal = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Detail") as? DetailViewController,
    let progress = goal.progress.first(where: {$0.goal.title == goal.title}) {
    vc.goalTitle = goal.title
    vc.date = progress.date
    
    if let comment = progress.comment {
        vc.comment = comment
    }
    
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

or set`returnsObjectsAsFaults` to `false`.

Here's a good [article](https://cocoacasts.com/what-is-a-core-data-fault) on the topic.